# How to catch table text value with querySelector

Tags: dom, web-scraping

I'm trying to catch a text line within a table. I've very close. When I'm entering the following line `document.querySelectorAll(“td”)[3]` in the console dev tool it return me this

`<td align="right"> $65.00 </td>`

However how do I get the `$65.00` value ?

When I'm using `document.querySelectorAll(“td”)[3].textContent` it not always working, sometimes I have a SyntaxError sometimes I have the value...

Comment: Note that `“td”` is not the same as `"td"` or `'td'`

Comment: Yep I starting to understand this. I know how to do this one " and this one ` but what is this one “ ? (I've copy and past it here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll("td")[3].textContent
```

Comment: Actually sometimes it is working sometimes not... I don't understand....

Answer (score 0):

You can just access innerText attribute and you will be returned a string with the required value

```
document.querySelectorAll("td")[3].innerText
```

This should give you the desired value

Comment: You can try putting brackets or storing the element in a temporary variable first

Comment: Syntax error is because of double quotation marks. @SimonBreton

Comment: double quotation marks ? you mean this " instead of ' ?

Comment: i thought the double quotes from question were not valid ones this one are working fine in my browser